# ES6: Tests pass in browser, fail with phantomJS, "Can't find variable: Reflect"

Tags: ecmascript-6, phantomjs, qunit

I am doing an ES6 rewrite for a js library.

```
class VerbalExpression extends RegExp {
    // snipped for brevity
}

/**
 * Alias for the constructor
 * @return {VerbalExpression} new instance of VerbalExpression
 */
function instantiate() {
    return new VerbalExpression();
}

// UMD (Universal Module Definition)
// https://github.com/umdjs/umd
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { // CommonJS
    module.exports = instantiate;
} else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) { // AMD Module
    define('VerEx', [], () => VerbalExpression);
} else { // Browser
    this.VerEx = instantiate;
}
```

When I run the tests in my browser, they all pass.

[image: tests pass in browser]

However, when I run the tests in the terminal, I get errors.

```
❯ npm test

verbal-expressions@0.3.0 test /Users/shreyasminocha/dev/open source/JSVerbalExpressions
grunt test

Running "qunit:files" (qunit) task
Testing test/index.html FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>> something
>> Message: Died on test #1 global code@file:///Users/shreyasminocha/dev/open%20source/JSVerbalExpressions/test/tests.js:7:5: Can't find variable: Reflect
>> Actual: null
>> Expected: undefined
>> ExtendableBuiltin@file:///Users/shreyasminocha/dev/open%20source/JSVerbalExpressions/dist/verbalexpressions.js:11:31
>> VerbalExpression@file:///Users/shreyasminocha/dev/open%20source/JSVerbalExpressions/dist/verbalexpressions.js:59:130
>> instantiate@file:///Users/shreyasminocha/dev/open%20source/JSVerbalExpressions/dist/verbalexpressions.js:588:32
>> somethingTest@file:///Users/shreyasminocha/dev/open%20source/JSVerbalExpressions/test/tests.js:8:26

...

Warning: 20 tests completed with 20 failed, 0 skipped, and 0 todo.
20 assertions (in 91ms), passed: 0, failed: 20 Use --force to continue.
```

**Note**: I am running the tests on compiled es6 code, that is, I run babel before running the tests.

I am guessing this is something to do with PhantomJS. How do I get the tests to pass in the terminal? Am I missing something? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stable PhantomJS doesn't support ES6 and is no longer in development, if  possible migrate to [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/) which is heavily inspired by PhantomJS.

Comment: How do I run Qunit tests using puppeteer with grunt?

Comment: Sorry, I always take my access to Google for granted... Could this help? https://dtaylor.uk/blog/2017/08/chrome-qunit/